# Angular directive and $q promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Please look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satz/cjXVc/)

I have created a directive for modal form based on [bootstrap modal](http://panthersoftware.com/blog/2013/05/09/a-reusable-bootstrap-modal-form-directive/). On the modal form submit, I want to call a function in main controller that in turn returns a promise. 
When the promise returns success, I close the form else I show the errors on the modal form.

I'm having trouble with handling the promise returned from controller login function.

```
                   var result = scope.formSubmit();
```

it's result as undefined!!

Not sure whats that I'm doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satz/a2TYt/1/) worked on angular 1.0.8.

```
 var result = scope.formSubmit();
```

already a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4214) reported in 1.2.0rc2. I need to workaround this issue.